# Why does cuDNN not load (GPU)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

im new in Neural Networks etc. and i wanted to download Keras-/Tensorflow-GPU, but it didn't worked properly. I have a Nvidia GTX 1080, and my Graphics Drivers are the newest. The CPU Version with Tensorflow works properly.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

And this is the error

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-95e0cf113d6b> in <module>
      1 y_train_car = y_train == 1
      2 
----> 3 model.fit(X_train, y_train_car, batch_size=128, epochs=10, shuffle=True)

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    194                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    195 
--> 196                 outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
    197                 outs = to_list(outs)
    198                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3725         value = math_ops.cast(value, tensor.dtype)
   3726       converted_inputs.append(value)
-> 3727     outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
   3728 
   3729     # EagerTensor.numpy() will often make a copy to ensure memory safety.

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1549       TypeError: For invalid positional/keyword argument combinations.
   1550     """
-> 1551     return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
   1552 
   1553   def _call_impl(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_impl(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1589       raise TypeError("Keyword arguments {} unknown. Expected {}.".format(
   1590           list(kwargs.keys()), list(self._arg_keywords)))
-> 1591     return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1592 
   1593   def _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs):

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node conv2d_1/convolution (defined at C:\Users\seyaf\.conda\envs\gputest\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_858]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

I have donwloaded Keras-GPU trough cmd and i use it with Anaconda, i also have updated Anaconda

Comment: What version of CUDA and Tensorflow-gpu are you running?

Comment: Tensorflow : 2.1.0, Cuda Version : 11.0

Comment: CUDA 11? The latest toolkit is 10.2

Comment: When i type nvidia-smi in cmd, it says CUDA Version 11.0

Comment: Install the Cuda development tool kit version 10.2 and try it out. Especially with Cuda, Tensorflow, and Kares, you will probably have to do a bunch of guessing and checking to make sure the different versions play nice with each other.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you installed the packages? Can you share the contents of the environment, using something like `conda list` ?

Comment: @Lowity, Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can share details as enquired above and the complete code. So that we can help you. Thanks!